# Generate VTT file from speech to text

Tags: audio-recognition, huggingface

I was able to generate text from an audio file using huggingface, using this code

```
transcriber = pipeline(
  "automatic-speech-recognition", 
  model="fsicoli/whisper-large-v3-pt-mzcv16"
)

transcriber.model.config.forced_decoder_ids = (
  transcriber.tokenizer.get_decoder_prompt_ids(
    language="pt", 
    task="transcribe"
  )
)

transcription = transcriber("half0.mp3")
```

Is there a way to output a vtt file? I get the transcription but not the timestamps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at using the [`return_timestamps` keyword](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/pipelines#transformers.AutomaticSpeechRecognitionPipeline.__call__.return_timestamps)? It seems you can also get the timestamps on either the word on text segment level (for the Whisper model at least).